# Install chrome extension for Enterprise policy in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On windows by using GPO we can install the chrome extension for enterprise policy.
But on Mac OS how we can installed the extension for enterprise policy.
By using preferences we can installed the extension silently but it is not for enterprise policy. I need to installed it for enterprise policy.
If any one know that how to installed the chrome extension for enterprise policy on Mac OS then please let me know.

Comment: Will [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453?hl=en) help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install chrome extension for enterprise policy. Use 'ExtensionInstallForcelist' as stated  [here](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist). By force installing we can specify all lists of apps and extensions that are installed silently, without user interaction. All permission requested by the apps/extensions are granted implicity. furthermore, permissions are granted for the 'enterprise.deviceAttributes' and 'enterprise.platformKeys' extension APIs.